# tracking civicontribute contributions with google ecommerce tracking

Tags: civicontribute

I need step by step guide to find out how and where i can enter the google analytics ecommerce tracking codes in civicrm drupal.

Comment: I'm certain no such documentation exists. You'll want to elaborate on exactly you'd like to do, what data needs to go where. The more information that you provide, the more the community would be better able to help you.

Comment: want  track the donations via GA ecommerce tracking

Comment: here's a pretty old blog article by somebody that did that for events: https://civicrm.org/blog/jcm55/adding-google-analytics-ecommerce-tracking-code-civicrmcivievent

Comment: here's another one, looks like somebody wrote an extensions at some point: https://civicrm.org/blog/vishalagarwal/gsoc-completion-report-on-integrating-google-analytics-with-civicrm

Comment: Here's the code for the extension, but it's 3 years old, may not be 100% compatible with current CiviCRM version https://github.com/VishalAgarwal/org.civicrm.webtracking